# How to format a text document while exporting from crystal reports?

Tags: c#, asp.net, printing, crystal-reports

I'm developing an online billing application with a direct printing option in ASP.Net . In order to achieve the direct printing, I'm using a windows service to send my bill directly to printer. I'm using crystal reports and exports the bill to a text file to disk using the following code

```
RptDoc.ExportToDisk(ExportFormatType.Text, Server.MapPath("~\\Transation\\print.txt"));
```

This method works well but i need to do some formatting(Bold some fields) in the text file.

Is there any way to do this while exporting.

Comment: `ExportFormatType.Text` exports as plain text, that by definition isn't styled.
If you want styled text, you can try `ExportFormatType.RichText`

Comment: But I'm using a windows service to print this text files. Also I have to sent this file to two printers at the same time. Its working with text print event handlers. sending to multiple printers not working properly when i'm using rtf or pdf formats.